# How to post dynamic ng-model list in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Model

```
public class DynamicModel
{
   public List<string> PayoutID { get; set; }
   public List<string> PayoutType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DynamicDiv(DynamicModel model)
{
  return View();
}
```

View With AngularJs Model Binding

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.Payout = {
                PayoutID: '',
                PayoutType: ''
            };
            $scope.SendDynamicData = function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/Home/DynamicDiv',
                    data: { model: $scope.Payout }
                }).success(function (data) {
                    alert(data.Message);
                }).error(function () {
                    alert("Something went Wrong");
                });
            };
        });
    </script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
@using (@Html.BeginForm("DynamicDiv", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter Payout ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Payout.PayoutID" name="Payout.PayoutID" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter Payout Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Payout.PayoutType" name="Payout.PayoutType" />
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Payout ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Payout.PayoutID" name="Payout.PayoutID" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Payout Type</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Payout.PayoutType" name="Payout.PayoutType" />
            </div>
    </div>

            <div class="form-group">

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="SendDynamicData()" value="Submit" />
        </div>
}
</div>
```

In the front if we add two or more text-boxes dynamically the values should be in the form of `list<string>`. *(If I am using one text-box (one `ng-model`) it is working fine.)*

How can I send those values to controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not make your model contain two list, but instead have a DynamicSomething that is one single node (with an ID and Type). Your model could than be a list of DynamicSomething that you can pass around.